# Don't requeue if transaction fails

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-batch, spring-amqp

I have a job with the following config:

```
@Autowired
private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Bean
Step step() {
    return steps.get("step")
        .<~>chunk(chunkSize)
        .reader(reader())
        .processor(processor())
        .writer(writer())
        .build();
}

@Bean
ItemReader<Person> reader() {
    return new AmqpItemReader<>(amqpTemplate());
}

@Bean
AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
    rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true);
    return rabbitTemplate;
}
```

Is it possible to change behavior of RabbitResourceHolder to not requeue the message in case of a transaction rollback? It makes sense in Spring Batch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not when using an external transaction manager; the whole point of rolling back a transaction is to put things back the way they were before the transaction started.

If you don't use transactions (or just use a local transaction - via `setChannelTransacted(true)` and no transaction manager), you (or an `ErrorHandler`) can throw an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` (or set `defaultRequeueRejected` to false on the container) and the message will go to the DLQ.

I can see that this is inconsistent; the RabbitMQ documentation says:

> On the consuming side, the acknowledgements are transactional, not the consuming of the messages themselves.

So rabbit itself does not requeue the delivery but, as you point out, the resource holder does (but the container will reject the delivery when there is no transaction manager and one of the 2 conditions I described is true).

I think we need to provide at least an option for the behavior you want.

I opened [AMQP-711](https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-711).

Comment: I see, but how could I do that with Spring Batch? The only way that I got this working was manually send to dlq in case of a failure

Comment: How/where are you using the listener container in Spring Batch, given that it's message-driven? In general it would be better if you explain your configuration more completely. I have a PR for the JIRA and it should be merged soon.

Comment: Or are you using `RabbitTemplate.receive()` operations?

Comment: Sorry. I've updated my question. Yes, I'm using an AmqpItemReader.

Comment: I was wondering if it makes sense in a chunk oriented setup because in case of a transaction rollback, the whole chunk would be rejected and I wouldn't know which item caused the rollback.

Comment: Right - you'd lose "good" messages along with the bad one. I can't really think of a good way to deal with this; after a rollback, on the second attempt, the `redelivered` message property will be `true` but the problem is you need to know (and discard) the "last" redelivered message, but you won't know which is the last until the next one (with redelivered=false) arrives.

Comment: I think that my best option is to implement this behavior manually. Thanks for your help.